# Product Variation Stock Count on Non WooCommerce Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock, product-variations

I'm needing to display the available "Stock" for some variations. The catch is that I need to do it on a static, standard WP page. I know the Product ID and Variation ID, can I use those to get the variation stock count, outside of WooCommerce's templates? I'm fine with using PHP or AJAX, I have a custom page template applied to that page already.

Comment: Where is your code attempt? We expected you to provide in your question your own real code attempt. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Comment: I couldn't find anyone talking about what I was wanting to do, so I didn't have any code at all when I posted. I've since pulled together some code from a couple of different answers here. I believe I have a working solution. I'll post it when I have a chance.

Answer (score 1):

This function can be called from any WordPress page, all you need to supply to the function is the main product ID, it must be a variable product and have variations setup to track inventory.

1. Makes the buttons
2. Checks how many are of that variation are in stock
3. shows a different button if the variation is sold out

   ```
    function getVariationButtons($productID) {
        $product = wc_get_product($productID);
        $count_in_stock = 0;

        if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' )) {

            $variation_ids = $product->get_children(); // Get product variation IDs

            foreach( $variation_ids as $variation_id ){
                $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);
                $varname = $variation->get_attribute_summary();
                $varid = $variation->get_variation_id();
                $varqty = $variation->get_stock_quantity();
                $varprice = $variation->get_price();
                if ($varqty > 0) {
                    echo ' <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/cart/?add-to-cart='.$varid.'">'.$varname.' Pass $'.$varprice.' ('.$varqty.' left)</a>';
                } else {
                    echo ' <a class="btn btn-default">'.$varname.' (Sold Out)</a>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```